# Connect to MySQL with Java

Tags: java, mysql

Okay im really new to java and i dont know how to really do it. if you guys could help me then i might understand alot more of it. I got my main class (Mysql.java) and a Connection class (Connection.java) Now i want it to Connect to the database using the Connection.java part. but i want to use it from Mysql.java. I got this right now:

***Mysql.java***

```
public class Mysql {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int w = screenSize.width;
        JFrame frame = new MainFrame(w/5, 100, 2*w/5, 0);
        frame.show();
        new Connection();
    }


}
class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    MainFrame(int width, int height, int x, int y) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Todothelydoo - To do planner");
        setSize(width, height);
        setLocation(x, y);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
}
```

***Connection.java***

```
public class Connection {
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://h2318966.stratoserver.net/";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "";
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connection established");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

I tried using new Connection in the mysql.java but im probably being an utter idiot. If you guys could help me that would be great.

Comment: You need to call the `getConnection()` method on the `Connection` instance you created in the main method for your `Mysql` class.

Comment: You have a class called `Connection` and you are trying to use `java.sql.Connection` in the same class. This presumably causes a name clash - call your class something else.

Comment: I got this: new Msqlconn.getConnection(); is this wrong? i dont understand. Im sorry

Comment: Okay i got it using the new msqlconn.java class and it shows up in the console but it gives an error on the ClassNotFoundException. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code with your own host and database name in url string. I have tested it.

Note: Include mysql-connector.jar in your project

Mysql.java

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Mysql {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int w = screenSize.width;
        JFrame frame = new MainFrame(w/5, 100, 2*w/5, 0);
        frame.show();
        try {
            new Connection().getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    MainFrame(int width, int height, int x, int y) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Todothelydoo - To do planner");
        setSize(width, height);
        setLocation(x, y);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
}
```

Connection.java

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Connection {
    public static java.sql.Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        java.sql.Connection conn = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "";
            conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connection established");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems to be working but everytime i run it the console just says: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
I installed it. why does the thing say this?

Comment: I have already told you include a JAR file into your project build path. Please download and include 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar' file in your project. you can find it here.
[link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar.zip)

Answer (score 0):

public class Mysql extends Connectionn{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int w = screenSize.width;
    JFrame frame = new MainFrame(w/5, 100, 2*w/5, 0);
    frame.show();
     Connectionn con=new Connectionn();
     try {
        con.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: public class Connectionn  {
public  void getConnection() throws SQLException {
Connection conn = null;        
  try
        {
       
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String url = "jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname";
String user = "username";
String password = "password";           
conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,password);
            System.out.println("Connection established");
        }
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
 {    
 }
catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        
    }
}

Comment: 1st create Mysql class and exted Conection class , create connection class object in Mysql class. call conection class method (getConnection()) and mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar  to be add in your project (Build Path) Libraries. then try it will works